# Run systemd service before any that are wanted by a given target

Tags: systemd

I'm trying to delay all user units `WantedBy=default.target` until such a time as the system's in a 'ready' state of my defining.

So I have a couple of `Type=oneshot` services that `RemainAfterExit=true`, and are `Before=` and `RequiredBy=default.target`. Their `ExecStart`s wait until (it is important, I have found, that they *wait* rather than than fail and restart) for the ready state, and then exit successfully, leaving the services active.

This works, as long as all of the user units are set to be `After=default.target` as well.

The problem is that that's the wrong direction really, they shouldn't need knowledge that I'm doing this, and some of them are outside of my control (I know I can override) being distributed by packages and enabled by my user.

Is there any way to specify that a service should run `Before` not only the stated target, but also anything that is triggered as a result of being `WantedBy` that target?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you want to run a service before some target kicks in. In that case you can put your service in a target which is before the default.target. Refer to https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/bootup.html

Note that all the targets in this page which are in the same level run concurrently.

PS:I can not comment on the question. This might not be a proper answer.

Comment: Thanks, but as I said in OP I do have the service(s) running before the `default.target` is deemed reached, as I want, the issue is that services `wantedby` that target may start before that target as well. I want to force them to wait for it, without having to edit/override them all.